# Garmin Communicator Plugin not working on any browser

Tags: garmin, internet-explorer, firefox

When I access the garmin plugin compatibility site.

Which one? This one: http://software.garmin.com/es-ES/gcp.html

I get the following notice: **[Browser name] No Longer Supports this Plugin**.

[image: Garmin notice]

On any browser.

This happens on different laptops.

I followed the instructions to enable the plugin on Internet Explorer, and it won't work.

Anybody else having the same issue?

Comment: try https://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=3607 download IE7+ (Windows Media Player 11 required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this question ended up in GIS stack exchange.
Garmin no longer supports the browser plugins. You'll need to install [garmin express](http://software.garmin.com/en-US/express.html) to manage and sync your device to garmin connect. If you have an account on strava you can also sync those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is something to do with Chrome and Firefox dropping support for NP-plugins (also known as legacy plugins or Netscape plugins) due to performance issues. You may try to install [Palemoon](http://www.palemoon.org/) browser, which is a fork of Mozilla Firefox with intent to support these plugins. It worked for me on a different plugin that failed.